# Django form validation with GET

Tags: django, forms, get

I have a form which allows users to select several parameters to allow faceted querying of data. As there is no data entry going on here I want the form to post to GET and I have a another view with a different template which displays the results.

I want the form to validate as normal so that if a required field is not completed the corresponding errors are displayed. At the moment my process looks like this (simplified):

my search view:

```
def search(request):
    ...
    context['form'] = GraphForm()
    ...
    return render(request, 'search.html', context)
```

my results view:

```
def results(request):
    if 'submit' in request.GET:
        # process GET variables as query
    ...
    return render(request, 'results.html', context)
```

my **search.html** template:

```
<form action="{% url results %}" method="get">{% csrf_token %}
{% for field in form %}
<div class="field_wrapper">
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Query"  />
</form>
```

Given that the form submits to another url with separate view code, what is the best way to go about validating (highlighting errors), and ensuring I have my GET data?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a little late, but I think the following will work while maintaining similarity to 'POST' workflow:

Instead of having two different views for searching and displaying results, just have one view. The [normal codepath](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#the-view) described for post forms can then be followed. Instead of using `request.method == 'POST'` to detect form submission, we instead use `'submit' in request.GET`. If using javascript to submit the form, make sure that 'submit' is included in the GET data or use a hidden field to detect form submission.

views.py

```
def search(request):
    context_dict = {}
    if 'submit' in request.GET:
        form = GraphForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            #do search and add results to context
            #If you don't want to use a single view, 
            # you would redirect to results view here.
            results = get_results(**form.cleaned_date)
            context_dict['results'] = results
    else:
        form = GraphForm()
    context_dict['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'search.html', context_dict)
```

search.html

```
<form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="get">
    {{form}}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Query"  />
</form>
{% if results %}
    {% include 'results.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass `request.GET` just like `request.POST` to the form. The form simply accepts a `data` dictionary. It doesn't care where that comes from. Have you already tried that?

Comment: I know that the bound form(data) will go through validation in my search view, just not sure what to do when the form validates - make a redirect with the passed GET data to the results view?

Comment: No, the results view receives the GET data, itself. The action on the form on your search view should be a link to your results view. In the results view, you instantiate the form just as in the search view, but this time you pass in `data` in the form of `request.GET`. Check that the form is valid, then render your results as normal.

Comment: Ok. And if the form is invalid - do I redirect back to the search view to display validation errors or display the form in the results page with the errors?

Comment: You'll have do it in the results view, since that's where the errors are. If you redirected back to the search page, you'll lose that information. This is why form handling is typically done all in the same view. Errors, then, just become another branch of logic.

Comment: OK. So I have it working now. My form directs to the `results` view. If valid, the data is processed and displayed in the `results.html` template. If the data is invalid, `request.GET` is saved to a session variable and redirects back to `search` view with a flag (something like `'/search/?errors=true'`), where the bound form can be displayed. I would welcome any suggestions as to why this may be bad practice.

Answer (score -2):

Use JavaScript/jQuery for form validation. All you need to do is add an id to `form`, and in the corresponding Javascript, do something like

```
document.getElementById("#form").onsubmit = checkForm();
```

or using jQuery

```
$("#form").submit(checkForm);
```

where `checkForm()` returns true upon successful validation, and false otherwise. (Note that, if you do not return false, form submission will continue as usual.)

Which fields you check for/validate can also change by using Django's templates.

Comment: Client-side validation is a great *in addition to* server-side validation, but it doesn't replace it. If you are relying entirely on client-side validation, you'll have problems.

Comment: @Chris I agree, but he seems to be asking for "make it obvious to the user" (i.e., client-side) features.

Comment: Ok, I understand that the javascript will work, but I though there might be some method in Django (server-side), as I feel that submitting form data via GET to another url should be a common task.

Comment: @Darwin I suppose you could do an ajax call, then submit the form if the server-side validator passes the inputs. Personally, I think it's inefficient for most applications, but I don't know your situation.

Comment: Hmmm. I am still not convinced by the client-side method (at least without a server-side solution also). Is there something fundamentally wrong with validating the form with GET in views? I mean, could I validate and save the GET data in request.session?

Comment: @Darwin There is nothing fundamentally wrong with validating using GET; it just adds a lot of overhead by making a network request. In other words, even if you have a blazing fast server-side validation script, most of the time you're waiting on the network request. With the client-side validation, everything's already there, so it can be somewhat slow, but still appear to validate much faster than if you had done it server-side. In the end, it all depends on what you want: client-side will be more speedy, but might not be able to catch all the errors that server-side validation would.

Comment: Client side & server side validation are not an "either-or" option. You need to do both. Client side for quick response, server side for catching malicious attacks.

Comment: @buffer Agreed, but it appeared he was only asking for form validation on the page (client-side), not server-side validation as well.